# How to set proxy in keystone js

Tags: amazon-s3, keystonejs

I am new in Keystone JS and I observed there is no much support available on google for it.
I am uploading files to S3 on AWS, but I am facing timeout issue, I figured out that, I need to set proxy for it. 
But I don't know how to set proxy in keystone, I searched on its site but found nothing.
Note:: I am using [keystone.storage](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/master/lib/storage) and [keystone-storage-adapter-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystone-storage-adapter-s3)

Answer (score 0):

The package keystone-storage-adapter-s3 that you are using is using knox, and knox's proxy support proxy was added in pull 137.

After make sure you have updated knox, you can add your proxy options to

```
var storage = new keystone.Storage({
  adapter: require('keystone-storage-adapter-s3'),
  s3: {
    key: 's3-key', // required; defaults to process.env.S3_KEY 
    secret: 'secret', // required; defaults to process.env.S3_SECRET 
    bucket: 'mybucket', // required; defaults to process.env.S3_BUCKET 
    proxy: '<your proxy>',
    ...
```

More information:

[Setting proxy server for connections in Knox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959774/setting-proxy-server-for-connections-in-knox)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystone-storage-adapter-s3

https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-storage-adapter-s3/blob/master/index.js

Note: I have not try this but I just provide the information based on the source code trace, good luck.